# Python "map or" on elements in list

Tags: python

What's the most elegant way of doing something like this:

```
>>> tests = [false, false, false]
>>> map_or(test)
false

>>> tests = [true, false, false]
>>> map_or(test)
true
```

The `map_or` function should return true if one or more of list elements are true.

Comment: @delnan indeed, wiki on this was enlightening. python `reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])` is more general way to do what I ask. tnx for this comment!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `any()`.  It is a built-in function that just does what you want.

Comment: Documented at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any.  Should also become familiar with `all()`.

Comment: Another interesting example of vote bias: although all three answers to this question are exactly identical, this one was voted up first, so it ended up with a wildly disproportionate score to the rest.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: Well, actually it was also posted first, though only by a few seconds.  But I'll give you a vote :)

Comment: @Glenn Maynard:  I had posted an answer to this question that was roughly the same as all the others.  I chose to delete my answer and vote for this one because it was posted first and it had roughly the same clarity of the other posts (although I winced at the second use of the word "just").  I also liked that the answer stated that `any()` is a built-in (not all the other answers did so).

Comment: @Steven: Just removed the first use of "just" :)

Comment: @Sven: That's exactly the trouble: it encourages people to answer as *quickly* as they can, strongly discouraging taking an extra couple minutes to write a good answer.  (It doesn't matter here, obviously--a trivial question and trivial answers--but it happens to questions of all complexity.)

Comment: @Glenn: This issue was [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).  (I just had a quick glance at the linked page.  I don't care about it to much.)

Answer (score 5):

```
any(tests)
```

Built in function :)

Answer (score 4):

```
any(tests)
```

(and the rest of this is padding because yet again StackOverflow treats users like idiots and sets minimum answer lengths)